# Can I redefine \begin so that it does not complain about undefined environment

Tags: errors, environments

I'd like to be able to do the following kind of thing:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
Foo
\begin{MyUndefinedEnv}
  Bar
\end{MyUndefinedEnv}
\end{document}
```

without `LaTeX` complaining about undefined environment. Is it possible without breaking existing environments?

Comment: Of course, I can patch the definition of `\begin` to remove the `\@latex@error` (p.204 of source2e.pdf). As a `\csname` is invoked it should not be a problem if the control sequence is not defined. But I'd like to hear it is safe from gurus `:)`.

Comment: Why do you want to use undefined environments? Just curious...

Comment: @marczellm Coding environments is a lot more fun than writing a whole lecture about the phase plane. So every time I need a new environment, I spend time coding it rather than doing the right thing `:)`.

Comment: @cjorssen: Hmmm, I think you are missing the whole point of procrastinating.. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\xbegin\begin % store original \begin
\let\xifundefined\@ifundefined % store original \@ifundefined
\def\begin{%
  % "inactivate" \@ifundefined, but only once, hence reverting
  % it to original definition immediately
  \def\@ifundefined##1##2##3{\global\let\@ifundefined\xifundefined##3}%
  \xbegin}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{ttgg}
Hello!
\end{ttgg}

\begin{center}
Hello!
\end{center}

\end{document}
```